# Does there exist a “fat” Thomae’s function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Definitions and some motivation:**

[Thomae’s function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function), also known as the raindrop function has several curious properties. One of which is the following - both its discontinuity set and continuity set are dense in $[0, 1]$, and also every discontinuity point is a removable discontinuity.

Can this happen in a “measure theoretic“ sense as well? In the sense that all the above conditions hold modulo null sets, in a way that is made precise below.

**Question set up:**

For a measurable function $f:\mathbb [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$, we say that $x \in \mathbb R$ is a *essentially removable discontinuity* of $f$ if

i) $f$ is not continuous at $x$,

ii) There exists a measure zero set $N$, and a measurable function $g: \mathbb [0, 1]  \to \mathbb R$ such that $g$ is continuous at $x$, and $g$ agrees with $f$ everywhere except possibly on $N$.

Note that here both $N$ and $g$ are allowed to depend on $x$.

> **Question:** Denote by $\mathcal E$ the set of essentially removable discontinuities of $f$, and $\mathcal C$ the set of continuity points respectively. Does there exist a function f such that $[0, 1]= \mathcal E \cup \mathcal C$ and such that both $\mathcal E$ and $\mathcal C$ have nonzero measure in any open interval?

Comment: Places to look (I don't have time now to dig into this): [Henry Blumberg's papers](https://zbmath.org/?q=ai%3Ablumberg.henry) (especially late 1910s through early 1920s, and measurable boundaries paper, and exceptional sets paper), Ákos Császár's early papers on negligent limits (e.g. [1](https://akjournals.com/view/journals/10473/6/3-4/article-p451.xml) and [2](http://acta.bibl.u-szeged.hu/13777/) and [3](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/cm/cm4/cm413.pdf) and [4](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0103.04002)), and Chapter 3 of [Thomson's book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540160588).

Comment: Comment on the terminology: typically one defines a discontinuity as essential on the real line if at least one of the one-sided limits fail to exist. The choice to call what you are defining an "essentially removable discontinuity" is a somewhat unfortunate clash.

Comment: I managed to look around a bit a few hours after my last comment and found some items and results that are more relevant, but I'm not going to have time to discuss them now and I also do not (yet) know the answer to your specific question. I'll try to write some kind of answer tomorrow, even if it only discusses what follows in a bit more detail. For now I'll mention that your generalized continuity condition is sometimes called "measure continuous", which unfortunately is a useless phrase for internet searching purposes. The notion is weaker than ordinary continuity (clear) **(continued)**

Comment: and stronger than approximate continuity [1](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Approximate_continuity) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/a/297099/15780) (less clear). Moreover, if a function is everywhere measure continuous then it is everywhere continuous, which incidentally is [not true for approximate continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1174420/13130). However, in your case we don't want a function that is everywhere measure continuous. I believe you want both $C$ and $MC - C$ to be [metrically dense](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22metrically+dense%22) sets.

Comment: I'm not going to have the time today to write a summary of what I've found/know. I'll try to get something written tomorrow for an "answer".

Comment: Ah it’s okay, take your time.

Comment: Update: A little over a week ago my contract work went from a nearly nonexistent trickle (past 2 months) to a wide open deluge, and there is also a huge amount of material I have on hand to sort through, so this will take a few more days. However, I think the result will be a useful survey of a lot of very little known literature, some of it I haven't thought about for 25+ years and some of it I've had unresolved questions about (from the 1990s) that I've never gotten around to sorting out (but I'm trying to now).

Comment: @Dave L Renfro Nice! I would be curious to know about some of the unresolved problems you have. If you don’t mind, you could share some of them with me!